# How to make url structure for products with categories tree name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to make url structure for products with their categories tree structure like below.

> www.site.com/main-category/sub-category/sub-category/.../product-name

Already I have defined in route.php for pages like

```
$route['(:any)'] = function ($slug) {
        return 'Page/show/'.$slug; };
```

Now what i should do for products ?